# Getting Error in cursor.execute while using mysql.connector in python

Tags: python, mysql-python

How to solve this problem:
I am getting error like EOF etc while executing the below code ----

My code is:

```
import mysql.connector as sql

db_con=sql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="XXXX",database="mydb")

db_cur=db_con.cursor()

db_cur.execute('"update Orders set Freight=case when ShipCountry='USA' then      Freight+(0.15*Freight)"' `" when ShipCountry='Canada' then Freight+(0.15*Freight)"``" when ShipCountry='France' then Freight+(0.10*Freight)"``" when ShipCountry='Germany' then Freight+(0.10*Freight)"``" when ShipCountry='Belgium' then Freight+(0.10*Freight)"``" else Freight+(0.05*Freight) end"`


how to solve?????
```

Comment: Please extend the sample of your code — at least to your erroneous line 14.

Answer (score 1):

Please close the brace for `db_cur.execute()` and follow the steps below.

1. Commit to the query
2. Close the cursor
3. Close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit INSERT and UPDATE queries and also close the connection after you are done.

It is best to use context managers

Like so:

```
import mysql.connector as sql
db_con=sql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="Redmilenovo#T",database="datagrokr")
with db_con.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""YOUR QUERY HERE""")

db_con.commit()
db_con.close()
```

You can also define the connection variable in a context manager as well.

Comment: I was not getting any error, but I forgot to commit & close :')

Answer (score 0):

> > EOF stands for End Of File. This error usually means that there was an open parenthesis somewhere on a line, but not a matching closing parenthesis.

```
db_cur.execute('"update Orders set Freight=case when ShipCountry='USA' then      Freight+(0.15*Freight)"' `" when ShipCountry='Canada' then Freight+(0.15*Freight)"``" when ShipCountry='France' then Freight+(0.10*Freight)"``" when ShipCountry='Germany' then Freight+(0.10*Freight)"``" when ShipCountry='Belgium' then Freight+(0.10*Freight)"``" else Freight+(0.05*Freight) end"`
```

if you observe their no close parenthesis